# Finding maximal independent sets of free variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination, homogeneous-equation

Given a system of homogeneous equations such as $$x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = 0\\x_2-x_4-x_5=0\\ x_3-x_5-x_6=0,$$

I am interested in finding maximal subsets of the variables $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ such that (1) the variables in the set can be assigned values  "freely", i.e. without constraint, (2) when those variables are specified, the system of equations uniquely determines the values of all other variables.

For example, in this case, $\{x_1, x_2,x_5\}$ and $\{x_4,x_5,x_6\}$ are maximal sets in this sense, while $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ fails to satisfy property (1), and $\{x_1, x_4\}$ fails to satisfy property (2).

This sense of "independence" feels like it should relate to the geometric/algebraic properties of the matrix representing this system of equations, but I do not see a direct connection to anything I know about, e.g. the null space or column space of a matrix. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Is there a straightforward way to find these sets?

---

Edit: Through "non-pivot" variables, Gaussian elimination can help identify a single independent set, which is a useful start. I am wondering how to  enumerate all such independent sets, or test a candidate set of variables for this property, or a geometric interpretation of these sets. It could be helpful to understand pivot rows through the language of linear operators rather than matrices.

---

From an operator perspective, I believe that at least the number of non-pivot variables is equal to the dimension of the nullspace of the operator. I am not sure what the relationship is between the different bases of the nullspace and the independent variable sets themselves.

Maybe this is useful: A subset $I$ of variables has this property iff there is a basis $\{b_i : i\in I\}$ for the null space such that for all $i,j \in I$, we have $b_{i,j} = \begin{cases}1&i=j\\0&i\neq j\end{cases}.$

Comment: Maybe there is a typo, but if you specify $x_1$ and $x_4$, the values of $x_2$ and $x_3$ are uniquely determined, so it satisfies property (2).

Comment: @Andrei Thanks I've tried an alternate example.

Comment: When you perform Gauss Jordan Elimination to get the Row Echelon form variables that do not have a pivot are the 'free' variables. So Gauss Jordan Elimination can help you find *a* maximal set of 'free' variables. If you are unfamiliar with these terms, you can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). Also, this [book](http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/) by Strang has very clear and easy to follow explanation regarding this idea.

Comment: @sudeep5221 . Yes, that's right, thanks. You can find a single set of free variables through row reduction. I'm wondering if there's a way of finding all such sets, or testing a candidate set for this property, and hopefully getting geometric intuition for what this property means.

Comment: Oh I see. One of the ways I think that might work is that using the zero and non-zero elements, in the Row Echleon form, one can specify a graph over the subsets of variables where edges represent the condition whether they are linked through an equation. Finding all sets can then be reduced to finding some property of this graph (perhaps, dominating set, though I think that is not case at least in formulation I tried). And then maybe you leverage existing results in graph theory to get your answer. I know this is just a direction but I feel that this might be worth pursuing.